# Connecting to different Azure AD tenants with PowerShell in an Azure Function App

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a system where PowerShell gathers data from multiple tenants and deplays in a report. One of the datapoints that needs to be checked, is whether administrators have MFA enabled or not. In order to pull this data, I use the following

```
$credentials = <credentials>;    
Connect-MSOLService -Credential $credentials;

foreach ($role in Get-MsolRole) {
    foreach ($adminUser in (Get-MsolRoleMember -All -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId -MemberObjectTypes @("User"))) {
        $isMFA = ($adminUser.StrongAuthenticationRequirements -match 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement').Count -gt 0;
        #Do stuff
    }
}
```

This works. Problem is, this script is running in a queue triggered azure function. It is triggered on a timer, meaning all triggers will run simultaneously. When the first connection is made, all other data requests pulls data from the same tenant.

Is there any way I can ensure each requests makes its own connection, or to limit the scope of the msol connection?

The only solution I can think of is running the scripts synchronous, but that would result in very poor performance.

Comment: How are you accounting for tenants that have enabled MFA for admins using a conditional access policy? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/baseline-protection#require-mfa-for-admins)

Comment: Is this the same function in a Functions App, triggered for different tenants? Or is it different functions in a Functions App, each function triggering for a different tenant?

Comment: It is the same function in a Functions App, each triggered with credentials for a different tenant. I have a variable number of tenants, so it has to be one single function.

Comment: What about the first question? How do you plan to address admins who have MFA enabled via conditional access, instead of per-user MFA?

Comment: 1) You mentioned that the script in running "in a queue triggered azure function" but that it is triggered on a timer. Which is the actual trigger? 2) Does $credentials need to be unique at every invocation of the Function?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I have no planned this yet, and I ignored the question because I did not feel like it related to this problem at hand.

Comment: @LingToh I have 3 functions for this, a timer function and a queue triggered function. The timer funciton runs in C#, and pulls user data etc. This data is then used to create an entry in a queue, where the PowerShell script is the triggered. And yes, the credentials need to be different, since I am contacting different tenants.

Comment: I don’t use Connect-MSOLService so have to ask, when you run Connect-MSOLService on your local machine, do you know if the credentials are stored in the Windows Credentials Manager?

Comment: @LingToh it does not appear so, no. I also cannot find documentation on this, so I would not know. The connection seems to be lost when I close PowerShell terminal, or when the azure function is completed. I cannot otherwise manually close the connection, or even keep a reference to said connection.

Comment: @anl_extrico Yes, you're correct that this is tangential to the problem you have right now, but it seems to me that you are incorrectly measuring users who are enabled for MFA, bringing this strategy all-up into question and possibly making your current problem a moot point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, when triggered by a queue, it would seem that multiple runs of the same function aren't at all isolated.

One approach you can take is to wrap your PowerShell code which should run isolated, into it's own PowerShell job, using `Start-Job`. Here's an example I tested successfully.

```
# Receive queue message
$input = Get-Content $queueItem -Raw

# Pass the input queue message as a parameter to a new job.
$job = Start-Job -ArgumentList $input -ScriptBlock {

    param($queueMessage)

    # Load the MSOnline PowerShell module 
    Import-Module $env:CONTOSO_PathToMSOnline

    # Retrieve the credentials from where they're securely stored
    $credentials = ... # e.g. get from Key Vault

    # Connect to Azure AD. This connection is only used by this job.
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $credentials

    # Do something with MSOnline...
}

# Wait for the job to complete, receive results, then clean up.
Receive-Job -Wait -Job $job -AutoRemoveJob
```

Based on my testing, this should cover your isolation needs. However, do keep in mind that you're spinning up a whole new PowerShell host instance for this, which might have unintended consequences (e.g. greater memory usage, more time to load).

While I'm at it, I'd like to suggest a tweak to your process to identify admins who have per-user MFA enabled (assuming you don't want to double-count admins who are members of multiple roles):

```
# Iterate over all admins of all roles, and check if they have per-user MFA enabled.

$admins = @{} # To keep track of which admins we've already seen

foreach ($role in Get-MsolRole) {

    $roleMembers = Get-MsolRoleMember -All -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId `#`
                                      -MemberObjectTypes @("User")

    foreach ($user in $roleMembers) {

        if ($admins.ContainsKey($user.ObjectId)) {
            # We've already seen this user, skip it.
        } else {
            $admins[$user.ObjectId] = $true # Mark as admin we've seen

            # Determine if per-user MFA is enabled or enforced
            $isMfaEnabledOrEnforced = $user.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -gt 0

            # Do something...    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems very promising. However, when running in a job, the function can no longer detect the MSOnline module. I also cannot seems to import it.

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting? Are you loading the MSOnline module from inside the job?

Comment: I have placed the module in the modules folder, so it should be auto-included when the function triggers. This worked before, without any code-line including the module. The exact error message is: "The term 'Connect-MSOLService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: This may be a difference in what module folders are pre-loaded in the Job. Try these two things: Import-Module MSOnline (hoping it picks it up from wherever it is already). If that doesn't work, try 2) Import-Module "C:/path/to/module/MSOnline.psd1" (telling it explicitly where the module is located).

Comment: For some reason I cannot possibly explain, using the full path worked - but only after updating the module. The auto-included version worked with the previous version, so I have no explanation for this.
However, the script now works as intended, and has not taken a noticable performance-hit. Thank you so much!!

Comment: In AF v2 apparently it won't work. I see the error `Note that 'Start-Job' is not supported by design in scenarios where PowerShell is being hosted in other applications`